# 'vertical-align: middle' does not work

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/abdulahhamzic/pen/rLBoOj

I'm trying to get the paragraphs (the name and other info of the stream) to be vertically aligned in the middle of their div parents. I'm trying this CSS code and it is not working:

```
.col-sm-4{
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Use tables, problem solved

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will your icon always be 73px? If so you could use that to extend the height of your name/other info.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbJVvG

```
.col-sm-4 p {
  line-height: 73px;
}
```