# Use 'vertical-align: middle;' do not work for me in CSS

Tags: html, css, wechat

I have two view in a super view, the code is below:

```
<view class="search">
<view class="section">
    <input id="input-word" placeholder="请输入您要查询的文本" focus/>
    <navigator id="cancel-button" class="navigator" url="../../index">取消</navigator>
    </view>
</view>
```

Before asking the question, I searched the SO, find :

['vertical-align: middle' does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631835/vertical-align-middle-does-not-work)

But I set the `line-height` equals to super view's heihgt, only one view(cancel-button) work, the other did not work.

The picture is below:

[image]

The css code:

```
#input-word {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
  line-height:90rpx;
}

#cancel-button {
  display:inline-block;
  width:120rpx;
  float:right;
  text-color:#ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height:90rpx;
}
```

Where is the issue? I think the code is no problem.

---

**Edit - 1**

```
#input-word {
  display:inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
  align-items: baseline;
  line-height:90rpx;
}
```

The input css I tested this, but not work.

Comment: Can you add a code fiddle?

Comment: You could start by writing valid HTML: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Have you tried assigning `width` to `#input-word` ?

Comment: @Rahul Chadrasekharan, what mean of assigning `width` to `#input-word` ? do you mean set width to 120 rpx too? I tested this ,but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

```
.section {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

---

**Origin**

Just Use following CSS

```
.section {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: yeah ,great, works, but the `cancel-button` do not float right now it stick left to the `input-word` now, how to avoid it ?

Comment: You can use `justify-content: space-between;` for this

Answer (score 0):

Use `inline-flex`, like in this example:

```
<div style="display: inline-flex;align-items: baseline;">
    <h4>This is a simple text </h4>
    <h1>Another simple text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Botond, I tested this, my first view is a input, look at my edit-1

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

<view class="search">
     <view class="section">
    <navigator id="cancel-button" class="navigator" url="../../index">取消</navigator>
    <input id="input-word" placeholder="请输入您要查询的文本" focus/>
    </view>
</view>
```

**Css**

```
#input-word {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float:right;
  text-align:left;
  line-height:90rpx;
}

#cancel-button {
  display:inline-block;
  width:120rpx;
  float:right;
  text-color:#ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height:90rpx;
}
```

[Click here to see Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j4e3z6d1/)